# exchange 2003 to 2007, recipient update services

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2003

going to try my best to explain:

our exchange 2003 was migrated to exchange 2007 (was not here for the migration).
Looking in active directory sites and services - > services - > Microsoft exchange - > company - > address list container - > recipient update services

i have two recipient update services

1) recipient update service (enterprise configuration)

2) recipient update service (my-domain)

my guess is one of these is left from the old exchange 2003. (im guessing this because the migration was not done properly, the exchange server was never actually uninstall, it was just taken offline, and then later disposed of).

could having two of these cause me issues, and if so, how do i know which one i could get rid of ?

Im asking because i honestly have no idea. it might even be nothing.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are both holdovers from Exchange 2003 as Exchange 2007 doesn't have or use the RUS. One of them (enterprise) is forest centric, and the other one (domain) is domain centric. I don't see any harm in them being there.

Comment: so the exchange 2007 server will not touch this information? The entire active directy sites and services, the exchange services every active directory entry is still on the server, will these cause issues?  I have never heard of a cleanup method other than uninstalling exchange, which is not a possibility for me anymore.

Comment: You can manually remove the Exchange 2003 information from AD but I don't have specifics about doing it with a mixed mode Exchange organization. You could try a /DisasterRecovery install of Exchange 2003 in order to remove it properly from the domain. Here are 2 articles that hopefully will help: http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Recovering-Failed-Exchange-2003-Member-Server-Using-Disaster-Recovery-Switch.html and http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/migration-deployment/removing-last-exchange-2003-server-exchange-2007-part1.html